# Flex div won't align to the left but to the right

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox

I have a bootstrap 4 header and I'm using flex in it for some custom layout.

Here is the html:

```
<nav class="navbar">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
      <img src="logo.png" alt="">
    </a>
    <div class="box">
      <div class="title">TITLE HERE</div>
      <div class="flex-inline-container">
        <div class="icon"><img src="icon1.png" alt="" /></div>
        <div class="icon"><img src="icon2.png" alt="" /></div>
        <div class="icon"><img src="icon3.png" alt="" /></div>
        <div class="icon"><img src="icon4.png" alt="" /></div>
        <div class="icon"><img src="icon5.png" alt="" /></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

And the CSS:

```
.box {
  display: flex;
  border-right: 2px solid #bfbfbf;
  width: min-content;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.box .flex-inline-container {
  display: inline-flex;
}

.box .icon {
  margin-right: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.box .title {
  position: relative;
  left: 7px;
  font-size: 1.40rem;
  font-weight:300;
  color: #727272 !important;
}
```

My issue is that the `"flex-inline-container"` div is going all the way to the right and I need it to be on the left.

How can I make it go to the left?

Comment: Can you make a simple drawing of how you expect it to look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.box {
  display: flex;
  border-right: 2px solid #bfbfbf;
  width: min-content;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.box .flex-inline-container {
  display: inline-flex;
}

.box .icon {
  margin-right: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.box .title {
  position: relative;
  left: 7px;
  font-size: 1.40rem;
  font-weight:300;
  color: #727272 !important;
}
```

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<nav class="navbar">
  <div class="container-fluid flex-row-reverse">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
      <img src="logo.png" alt="">
    </a>
    <div class="box">
      <div class="title">TITLE HERE</div>
      <div class="flex-inline-container">
        <div class="icon"><img src="icon1.png" alt="" /></div>
        <div class="icon"><img src="icon2.png" alt="" /></div>
        <div class="icon"><img src="icon3.png" alt="" /></div>
        <div class="icon"><img src="icon4.png" alt="" /></div>
        <div class="icon"><img src="icon5.png" alt="" /></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: The logo has gone to the right. I need the logo first and then any boxes, .box floated to the left (as there could be multiple .box divs)

Answer (score 2):

The `.container-fluid` class of bootstrap has a `Justify-content:space-between` property. Which distributes items evenly (The first item is flush with the start,
the last is flush with the end).

In your case the `<a class="navbar-brand"><a>` will be moved to first and elements inside `<div class="box"></div>` moved to last.

If you want to override Justify-content property of `.Container-fluid` and move to left, Then add a `.justify-content-start` along with `.Container-fluid`.